# Extending a numpy 3D array with additional features using a pandas dataframe for LSTM training

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I am trying to extend an existing numpy 3D array called dataset_array with shape (x, y, z) by adding additional features for an LSTM model, so that the new array has a shape of (x, y, z+5). The z axis represents the number of features and the y axis represents the number of timesteps or history.

I also have a pandas dataframe called df1 with 6 columns. The first column in df1 contains datetime values in 1 minute intervals. I want to match these datetime values with the datetime values in dataset_array[:, -1, 0], which are in 5 minute intervals. Before proceeding, I will use the pd.to_datetime() function to ensure that all datetime values are in the same format.

My task is to search for every dataset_array[:, -1, 0] value in df1.datetime. If an exact match is found, then I will take the matching row and the y number of rows above it (including the matched row), and append the third axis z+1 to z+5 of dataset_array with the remaining columns in that row from df1 (except the datetime column). The data should be appended to the end of the third axis of dataset_array, so that the new features occupy the last 5 indices of the third axis.

If there is no exact match found for a dataset_array[:, -1, 0] value in df1.datetime, then I should subtract 1 minute from the value and search again in df1.datetime. I will keep subtracting 1 minute and searching until a datetime value is found in df1. When I find a match, I will follow the same process as described above to add the new features to dataset_array.

**I tried:**

```
import numpy as np

dataset_array[:, -1, 0] = pd.to_datetime(dataset_array[:, -1, 0])
df1['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['datetime'])

# Sort df1 by datetime column in ascending order
df1 = df1.sort_values('datetime')
(x, y, z) = dataset_array.shape
# Create a copy of dataset_array with additional 5 features
new_array = np.zeros((x, y, z+5))
new_array[:, :, :z] = dataset_array

# Search for exact matches and append corresponding rows from df1
for i in range(x):
    for j in range(y):
        dt = dataset_array[i, j, -1]
        row = df1[df1['datetime'] == dt]
        while row.empty and j > 0:
            j -= 1
            dt -= pd.Timedelta(minutes=1)
            row = df1[df1['datetime'] == dt]
        if not row.empty:
            new_array[i, j:(j+z+5), z:] = row.iloc[0, 1:]

# Reorder new_array by ascending datetime values
new_array = new_array[np.argsort(new_array[:, :, -6]), :, :]

# Reassign dataset_array to new_array
dataset_array = new_array
```

**But got**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_27/1170559654.py in <module>
     13 # Create a copy of dataset_array with additional 5 features
     14 new_array = np.zeros((x, y, z+5))
---> 15 new_array[:, :, :z] = dataset_array
     16 
     17 # Search for exact matches and append corresponding rows from df1

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2011-02-09 18:10:00.000'
```